# Pandas not consistently skipping input number of rows for skiprows argument?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using Pandas to organize CSV files to later plot with matplotlib. First I create a Pandas dataframe to find the line containing 'Pt'. This is what I search for to use as my header line. [header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htLlY.png)

Then I save the index of this line and apply it to the skiprow argument when creating the new dataframe which I will use.

Oddly, depending on the file format, even though the correct index is found, the wrong line shows up as the header. For example, note how in Pandas line 54 has 'Pt" right after the tab:

[correct index on first file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZFgF.png)

The dataframe comes out correctly here.
[correct dataframe on first file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHBb4.png)

For another file, line 44 is correctly recognized with having 'Pt'.
[correct index on second file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEO8d.png)

But the dataframe *includes line 43 as the header!*
[incorrect dataframe on second file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlTX7.png)

I have tried setting header=0, header=none. Am I missing something?

Here is the code

```
entire_df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)

print(entire_df.head(60))
header_idx = -1
for index, row in entire_df.iterrows(): # find line with desired header
    if any(row.str.contains('Pt')):
        print("Yes! I have pt!")
        print("Header index is: " + str(index))
        print("row contains:")
        print(entire_df.loc[[index]])
        header_idx = index # correct index obtained!
        break

df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter='\t', skiprows=header_idx, header=0) # use line index to exclude extra information above

print(df.head())
```

Here are sections of the two files that give different results. They are saved as .dta files. I cannot share the entire files.

**file1** (properly made dataframe)

```
FRAMEWORKVERSION    QUANT   7.07    Framework Version
INSTRUMENTVERSION   LABEL   4.32    Instrument Version
CURVE   TABLE   16875
Pt  T   Vf  Im  Vu  Pwr Sig Ach Temp    IERange Over
#   s   V   A   V   W   V   V   deg C   #   bits
0   0.1 3.49916E+000    -1.40364E-002   0.00000E+000    -4.91157E-002   -4.22328E-001   0.00000E+000    1.41995E+003    11  ...........
1   0.2 3.49439E+000    -1.40305E-002   0.00000E+000    -4.90282E-002   -4.22322E-001   0.00000E+000    1.41995E+003    11  ...........
2   0.3 3.49147E+000    -1.40258E-002   0.00000E+000    -4.89705E-002   -4.22322E-001
```

**file2** (dataframe with wrong header)

```
FRAMEWORKVERSION    QUANT   7.07    Framework Version
INSTRUMENTVERSION   LABEL   4.32    Instrument Version
CURVE   TABLE   18
Pt  T   Vf  Vm  Ach Over    Temp
#   s   V vs. Ref.  V   V   bits    deg C
0   2.00833 3.69429E+000    3.69429E+000    0.00000E+000    ........... 1419.95
1   4.01667 3.69428E+000    3.69352E+000    0.00000E+000    ........... 1419.95
2   6.025   3.69419E+000    3.69284E+000    0.00000E+000    ........... 1419.95
3   8.03333 3.69394E+000    3.69211E+000    0.00000E+000    ........... 1419.95
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to your indentation levels. Your code block in which you want to set the `header_idx` depending on your `if any(row.str.contains('Pt'))` condition has the same intendation level as the if statement, which means it is executed at each iteration of the for loop, and not just when the condition is met.

```
for index, row in entire_df.iterrows():
    if any(row.str.contains('Pt')):
    [...]
    header_idx = index
```

Adapt the indentation like that to put the assignment under the control of the if statement:

```
for index, row in entire_df.iterrows():
    if any(row.str.contains('Pt')):
        [...]
        header_idx = index
```

Comment: I apologize: that was a result of me copying the code. It is properly indented in the script and I have adjusted my post.